# iOS7.0 Intermittent Crashes

Tags: ios7, ios7.1

Team,

Once I upgraded my application to iOS 7.0 with Xcode 5, I see intermittent crashes in the application. if I compile with xCode 4.2 and I don't see any intermittent crashes on iOS7 device. 
I hope the below crashes are memory related, because it occurs at different places in the application.

Please find logs

```
Apr  1 14:07:57 My-AD-Username ADTCommercial[185] <Notice>: [AMPMessageDispatcherThread handleMessage:] message {jlodigkeit-41-1396382877074} received on Outbound-msg-dispatcher for processing, MIM: 29, MID: 0
Apr  1 14:07:57 My-AD-Username ReportCrash[192] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 185
Apr  1 14:07:57 My-AD-Username ReportCrash[192] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process ADTCommercial[185]
Apr  1 14:07:57 My-AD-Username com.apple.debugserver-300.2[184] <Warning>: 21 +523.616314 sec [00b8/060b]: RNBRunLoopLaunchInferior DNBProcessLaunch() returned error: 'failed to get the task for process 185'
Apr  1 14:07:57 My-AD-Username com.apple.debugserver-300.2[184] <Warning>: error: failed to launch process /Developer/usr/bin/debugserver: failed to get the task for process 185
Apr  1 14:07:57 My-AD-Username com.apple.debugserver-300.2[184] <Warning>: 22 +0.002490 sec [00b8/1207]: error: ::read ( -1, 0x3469ec, 18446744069414585344 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)
Apr  1 14:07:57 My-AD-Username com.apple.debugserver-300.2[184] <Warning>: Exiting.
Apr  1 14:07:57 My-AD-Username com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.adt.commercial.mobility.dev[0xdd96][185]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.adt.commercial.mobility.dev[0xdd96]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Apr  1 14:07:57 My-AD-Username backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.adt.commercial.mobility.dev[0xdd96]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11


Apr  1 14:09:26 My-AD-Username ADTCommercial[194] <Notice>: [ADT_JobDetailsScreenServiceHistoryScreen loadData:create:preload:] called
Apr  1 14:09:26 My-AD-Username ADTCommercial[194] <Notice>: [AMPScreenManager viewWillPop:] popped ADT_ServiceHistoryDetailsScreen from history
Apr  1 14:09:27 My-AD-Username ADTCommercial[194] <Notice>: # -[JobDetailsScreen(Custom) refreshAction] #....
Apr  1 14:09:27 My-AD-Username ReportCrash[196] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 194
Apr  1 14:09:27 My-AD-Username ReportCrash[196] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process ADTCommercial[194]
Apr  1 14:09:27 My-AD-Username com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.adt.commercial.mobility.dev[0xd929][194]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.adt.commercial.mobility.dev[0xd929]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Apr  1 14:09:27 My-AD-Username backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.adt.commercial.mobility.dev[0xd929]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
```

I believe, its memory related crashes. Any idea why?

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: Those logs don't say anything useful. You need to look at/post the actual crash reports (with stack traces, etc).

Comment: If you think it's memory related, have you run the profiler?

Comment: Yes. I do see leaks.. I am curious to know what makes the difference with Xcode 4.2 and Xcode 5?